# Data fetched from API correctly; app gives TypeError with 'undefined' variable while processing with 'computed'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I ran into troubles trying to process data fetched from remote API.

The app is running VueJS with Vuetify, data is formatted with Vuetify's data table component.

This is my code:

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'City', value: 'city' },
        { text: '#Citizens', value: 'citizens' },
        { text: '#Schools', value: 'schools' },
        { text: 'Schools per Citizen', value: 'schoolsPerCitizen' },
(...)
```

API URL is defined as a variable on the root level of the app.

Then, there is this method launched when `created()` kicks in:

```js
methods: {
    loadData() {
      axios.get(citiesApiUrl)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data) // data displayed correctly
          return response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {console.error(error)})
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.loadData()
  }
```

As you noticed in the comment, `response.data` does display desired values.

Problems start from this point:

```js
computed: {
  stats() {
    return this.loadData().map(item => {
      item.schoolsPerCitizen = (item.schools / item.citizens).toFixed(2)
      return item
    })
  }
}
```

I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Comment: maybe when you try to do `this.loadData().map`, what happens is `this.loadData()` hasn't been defined yet

Comment: @Scaramouche: it may be so! Just removed call to `loadData()` from `created()`. Now at first, I get the error, then the data fetched from API gets displayed! The question is, how to make it work asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues**

- When `loadData` is called in `created`, the axios promise is consumed but nothing happens with the returned data except it's logged and returned to the promise resolver.
- When `loadData` is called in `stats` (computed), `.map` is chained off of the return value from `loadData`, but `loadData` has no return value.
- Even if `loadData` returned the axios promise, that promise would have to be consumed in `stats` first before accessing the data (needs `.then`)
- The design is flawed because the computed will make an identical API call every time it recalculates, which is likely unnecessary.
- Also, the promise returned by `stats` wouldn't be resolved by the template render function anyway.

**Fix**

Create a variable for the loaded data (I'll call it `mydata`):

```js
data() {
  return {
    // ...
    mydata: []
  }
}
```

Change `loadData` to:

```js
loadData() {
  axios.get(citiesApiUrl).then((response) => {
    this.mydata = response.data // <--- Set the data to `mydata`
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
}
```

Change `stats` to:

```
stats() {
  // This is also not designed properly, it's going to mutate `mydata`...
  // You should study Vue and learn what the purpose for computeds are before using them
  return this.mydata.map(item => {  // <-- Once `mydata` is populated, this will recalculate
    item.schoolsPerCitizen = (item.schools / item.citizens).toFixed(2)
    return item
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dan, thanks for broad explanation. After changes proposed by you the data gets fetched and displayed correctly; there's only an issue with `schoolsPerCitizen`: it doesn't appear in the table among other values. `console.log()` call put inside `stats() {...}` seems not to be reached at all.

Comment: You're welcome.  Are you using `stats` in the template?  If not, there's no reason for it to calculate.  And your `computed` is going to mutate your data which is bad too.  But I think it's time for a new question for that.

Comment: Yeah..., that was it, my bad! ;-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

loadData does not return any value.

```
loadData() {
  return axios.get(citiesApiUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data) // data displayed correctly
      return response.data
    })
    .catch(error => {console.error(error)})
}
```